# rails custom date validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, activerecord

In the form the user has to choose a month and a year. I'd like to make sure that the date is not in the future based on the month. So let's say the current date is 07/01/2016 in which case the user should be able to choose 07/2016 but shouldn't be able to choose 08/2016.

The validation seems to be working, but doesn't look well. Is there an easier way
achieve this?

```
validate :founded_in_the_past

def founded_in_the_past
  if founded && ((founded.month > Date.current.month && founded.year == Date.current.year) 
    && founded.year > Date.current.year)
      errors.add :base, "Founding date must be in the past."
  end
end
```

Comment: That condition looks like it will always be false: `founded.year == Date.current.year` and `founded.year > Date.current.year`. I assume you meant that last `&&` to be `||`?

Comment: lurker you are right. The last one should be `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking with month and year why you are not comparing date directly by creating date object using month and year.

```
validate :founded_in_the_past

def founded_in_the_past
  if founded && (Date.new(founded.year, founded.month, 1) > Date.current)
    errors.add :base, "Founding date must be in the past."
  end
end
```

In your code if you select year as `2017` and month as `5` - it will allow to select this date

```
founded && ((founded.month > Date.current.month && 
  founded.year == Date.current.year) && 
  founded.year > Date.current.year)
```

> founded = true
>
> founded.month > Date.current.month = false
>
> founded.year == Date.current.year = false
>
> founded.year > Date.current.year = true

If we map this in your condition you condition will look like

> true && ((false && false) && true)

This will return false and it will allow user select future date

Comment: Sampat you are right I used the wrong operator. The last one should be `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out one conditional by using `>=` eg

```
if founded && (founded.month > Date.current.month && founded.year >= Date.current.year)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Taryn! Shouldn't be just `founded.month > Date.current.month` instead of `founded.month >= Date.current.month` ? Current month should be regardless the day